# how to use a varible to tell which range to use in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is a part of my code, in fact, I just want to use two variables to control the range I want to use, but it keeps give my range failed error, I think there may some wrong on where I write the range statement here, so anyone know how to fix it?

```
Dim d As Long, f As Long
d= Templete.Worksheets("Telogis Data").Range("b2").End(xlDown).Row
f = Templete.Worksheets("Telogis Data").Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
Templete.Worksheets("Telogis Data").Range("J" & d, "L" & d).AutoFill Destination:=Range("J" & d, "L" & f), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Thx
Pudge

Comment: Are you intending to set `d` and `f` to the same values?

Comment: no, i edited the question, they are different values, but the problem shold in the range statement,,

Comment: Use `Range().Offset()` to pick a cell using row/column variables

Comment: Follow the suggestions on my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347692/vba-relative-cell-reference-in-loop

Comment: Still confused.. let us say for example, if e is a varible, I can use Range("C7:C" & e), how can write a range with a varible to replace 7, but it will not generate range failed message..

Comment: @WorstSQLNoob do you want something like the last row/column number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, there is nothing wrong with your AutoFill line.

I suspect you are mis-calling the ranges when you set your variables.

I cannot find an excel reference for `Templete`